# php: array_uintersect with dynamic number of arrays

Tags: php, dynamic-arrays

I have a `foreach` loop that returns a variable number of arrays.

I need to run `array_uintersect` between them with a custom function to find common elements, but `array_uintersect` only accepts 3 parameters (2 arrays and the function).

This is what I have right now:

```
$all_freaktag_favorites = array();

foreach ($serie_preferite as $serie_preferita) {
    $preferite_elements = pods('category', $serie_preferita['term_id']);
    $freaktag_preferita = $preferite_elements->field('freaktag');

    $all_freaktag_favorites[] = $freaktag_preferita;
}

function comparaFreaktag($tag1, $tag2) {
    return strcmp($tag1['term_id'], $tag2['term_id']);
};

$common_freaktag_between_favorites = array_uintersect(
    $all_freaktag_favorites[0],
    $all_freaktag_favorites[1],
    'comparaFreaktag'
);
```

This correctly returns me the intersection between the first 2 arrays in the loop, but I don't know how to do that with an undefined number of arrays.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all arrays into a parent array and use the spread operator:

```
$all = [[/** xxx */, [/** xxx */], [/** xxx */], ...];

$all[] = 'comparaFreaktag';

$common_freaktag_between_favorites = array_uintersect(...$all);
```

Comment: Thanks @Marvin, I'm already wrapping all arrays into `$all_freaktag_favorites[]` so I change your code in: `$common_freaktag_between_favorites = array_uintersect(...$all_freaktag_favorites, 'comparaFreaktag');` but doing so I'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Cannot use positional argument after argument unpacking`

Comment: I edited my answer, `comparaFreaktag` will now be added as the last element of the `$all` array and the function detects when a callable / string is given and takes it as the last argument. Tested here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3171a01f755a2d88dee8429141e943f6c5d00c2b

Comment: sorry for bothering, is there a way to return the most repeated elements instead of the exact intersection?

Comment: Better open a new question for that